# 'No document windows are open' error

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Here's a conundrum I've discovered.

I have a script that opens a file in InDesign, does some work to it, then closes it.  To help speed it up, I have turned off displaying the file by using the `false` argument while opening the file, like so:

```
var document = app.open(oFile, false);
```

Sometimes, while doing some work on an open file, the script may need to need to resize a certain page from 11 inches tall to 12.5 inches tall, thusly:

```
    if (padPrinted) {
        for (var p = 0; p < outputRangeArray.length; p++) {
            var padPage = document.pages.item(outputRangeArray[p]);
            if (padPage.bounds[2] - padPage.bounds[0] === 11) {
                padPage.select();
                var myY1 = padPage.bounds[0] -= 0.75;
                var myX1 = padPage.bounds[1];
                var myY2 = padPage.bounds[2] += 0.75;
                var myX2 = padPage.bounds[3];
                padPage.reframe(CoordinateSpaces.INNER_COORDINATES, [[myX1*72, myY1*72], [myX2*72, myY2*72]]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This has been working flawlessly for me for quite some time, but now it sometimes errors on the line `padPage.select()` with the message:

> No document windows are open.

If I go back to the line which opens the file and delete the `false` argument, then the script works fine.

So, I'd like to know if there's any way to get around this.  I'd like to have the documents open without displaying them, but still have the ability to resize a page when I need to.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you call `padPage.select();`? It doesn't look like your code needs it.

**Edit:**

On page to page 42 of the [Adobe InDesign CS6 Scripting Guide: Javascript](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf), there is a sample snippet that reframes the page and doesn't call `select()`. The snippet comes from a sample script in the [InDesign CS6 Scripting SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk/eula_cs6.html) (scroll to the bottom).

The path of the sample script is *Adobe InDesign CS6 Scripting SDK\indesign\scriptingguide\scripts\JavaScript\documents\PageReframe.jsx*

Inspecting this script, we see that it never calls `select()`. In fact, the *PageResize.jsx* never calls `select()` either.

Also, while InDesign Server can resize and reframe pages, you'll notice that the `select()` function is [missing entirely](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6serverjs_html/idcs6serverjs/pc_Page.html). It would seem that `select()` affects only the GUI.

In the face of all this evidence, I would wager that the scripting guide is wrong when it says "you must select the page". Try removing that line and see if it works.

**Edit 2**

On an unrelated note, the following lines might be troublesome:

```
var myY1 = padPage.bounds[0] -= 0.75;
var myX1 = padPage.bounds[1];
var myY2 = padPage.bounds[2] += 0.75;
```

The `+=` and `-=` operators will attempt to modify the bounds directly, but the bounds are read-only and can only be modified with methods such as `resize` or `reframe`. I would recommend changing it to this:

```
var myY1 = padPage.bounds[0] - 0.75;
var myX1 = padPage.bounds[1];
var myY2 = padPage.bounds[2] + 0.75;
```

Comment: According to page 41 of the [Adobe InDesign CS6
Scripting Guide: Javascript](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf), "Before changing a page’s size or applying a transformation to the page, you must select the page."

Comment: @Sturm My response was too long, so I edited my answer instead.

Comment: That was it.  I remember trying to use the `.reframe()` method before without success, but the `.select()` method on the page made it work.  Or perhaps I am just remember incorrectly.  Regardless, you are correct about the snipped on page 42—I never noticed the omission of `.select()` in it before.

Also, thanks for catching that `+=` and `-=` gaffe.  I originally tried to get it to work without assigning those to variables, but I soon discovered that `bounds` are read-only and forgot to remove the assignment operator afterward.

Thanks again, dln385, you are awesome!